# Should there be experts to review disputable answers?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes the community does not really judge an answer on its correctness, but rather on the reputation of the one who answers (or some other reasons).

For example, although the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138420/classes-without-default-constructors/20138614) got the most votes, it does not correctly answer the question (read the comments to see why). While the third answer (by me) tries to take into account of what the OP wants and provides the closest solution, it got downvoted.

Should there be experts to review this kind of disputable situation?

Comment: `So should there be experts to review this kind of disputable situation?` yeah. But how can we identify those experts?... Let me think. Maybe using some sort of score? We could call it clout. Or perhaps even better, reputation. :)

Comment: Seriously though, yes, sometimes the community votes „wrongly“, but the community vote is what we have. It’s generally agreed moderators can’t determine the correctness of an answer. (Note that I can’t judge whether your answer is any better than juanchopanza’s.)

Comment: This is probably one of the flaw of the system. Someone that answers 100k questions and got 200k reputation may not be a real expert...

Comment: You're starting from a false premise in my opinion *"the community do not really judge an answer on its correctness, but rather the reputation of the one who answers (or some other reasons)."*

Comment: The community is generally very reliable in voting up correct answers, and voting down incorrect ones, regardless of who wrote them. Your example, even if you’re right, is not evidence that there is a global trend going the other direction - especially since there seems to be disagreement over what is „correct“ and what is „incorrect“ here

Comment: @Pekka: Yeah I do not have a strong example, as the most voted answer got only 3 votes. I remember saw some though.

Comment: @Pekka웃: I agreed it is not the trend. The community works most of the time. However they can get wrong in some situation. How can we deal with it?

Comment: @Krypton other than bringing it up in a related chat room, there’s no real venue to discuss cases like this I’m afraid. Meta is theoretically an option in extreme cases (e.g. where a very dangerous answer is the most upvoted), but it can easily backfire.

Comment: Well I think we can only accept it. Remember how the community reacted when Galileo proposed his theory about the solar system.

Comment: It might be that your answer is downvoted because it presents a solution which is more of a fallback to how you would do it in C rather than a proper C++ solution. An answer can be technically correct but still frowned upon by the "community" that frequents the tag. That is just me guessing though.

Comment: By definition juanchopanza is more an expert than you. The gold c++/c++11/stl badges should be an indicator for that.

Comment: @Gimby I'm a down voter and I can tell you why.  The answer has undefined behavior.  That makes it not usable.  IMHO a not usable piece of code is not useful and down votes are for not useful answers.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I can tell you that I tested it 1000 times before posting the answer. If you set x after malloc, the behavior is 100% defined http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/893804819dbfb3be

Comment: So now with more downvotes on my answer, this becomes a stronger example.

Comment: this is the meta effect. But people here try not to teach people dangerous code style. When people see your code and immitate it without understanding it this answer makes the world a bit worse instead of better. And this should be your goal when you answer.

Comment: @Krypton Just because it compiles does not mean it is broken.  There are plenty of cases where UB compiles.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I did run it and and run valgrind for memory leaks, not just compiled onlly...

Comment: @Krypton on how many compilers?

Comment: @Hayt: on llvm clang only

Comment: On MSVS the output is `_x = 1_x = 2_x = 3_x = 4_x = 5177426_x = 3014739_x = 5177420_x = 4259907_x = 76_x = 5439573`.  Different output from the same code means either UB or one of the compilers is broken.  Even with all the problems MSVS has this is not a compiler bug.  You have to understand the subtle language rules that you are breaking even though it compiles and it "works".  Breaking those rules means all bets are off.

Comment: @Krypton thats the thing with UB. every compiler can do what they want. In theory I can write my own compiler which is standard conform and will format your hard drive if someone does UB. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420753/unspecified-undefined-and-implementation-defined-behavior-wiki-for-c

Comment: @NathanOliver you should have read the code, I only set the first 4 values. If I set the rest, there would not be those random numbers anymore.

Comment: @Krypton in the end you are still just downvoted because you encourage what it seen as bad practice and the "experts" are saying that. Just by a look on the profiles of NathanOliver and juanchopanza seem to indicate they are more an expert than you in C++. So somehow the system works.

Comment: It takes a special kind of expert to brush off undefined behavior like that, @Krypton. Maybe, just maybe, your idea of your own expertise is not correlated to reality.

Comment: @Hayt: It would be impartial to see the profile and reputation and judge if someone is the expert. It would seem like to only. The community tends to advocate those so-called experts with high reputation, and against the strange stuffs that they have never seen.

Comment: @Krypton I did not check the reputation. I have seen high-rep users with bad questions in c++. I checked the badges. You get bronze/silver/gold badges in the tag when you have a certain amount of reputation / good answers in that. Also I assume these people understand what you are doing there so don't think they just don't "get you" . It is clear what you intend and people have been down that road before and did things like that. You become an expert if you at some point recognize the pitfalls in that and start teaching people not to do this.

Comment: @Hayt: as you could see from the previous chat, Nathan Oliver, an expert, did not even know that my code would not cause UB. And then he was trying to convince me that my code is bad and to teach people not to to do this.

Comment: @Krypton He never said it does not compile. You assumed he said that maybe. he told you "just because something compiles does not mean it's right"

Comment: I'm sorry it's a typo - it's to cause UB (instead of compile). He did not even read the code to realize I initialized only first 4 items, and said that I got "different output from the same code"

Comment: it does cause UB. just because a compiler behaves the way you expect it does not make it defined. Defined is everything which is defined in the c++ standard. your case is simply not. People can develop compilers where this won't work and it will still be a valid c++ compiler. I think you are currently just stuck in the 2nd phase of this: https://cdn2.omidoo.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/full_width/images/bydate/201506/thumbnail.jpg People have been there and are "armed" with the knowledge how most c++ compiler align the memory. At some point you will see the risks with this approach.

Comment: @Hayt: another impartial judgement again, both you and I and many people here cannot tell if it is not defined in the C++ standard. Although I'm far from an expert, I obviously know what I'm talking about. It's also quite imprudent of you to judge a person when not knowing anything about him/her. What if I'm a person at the 3rd phase or beyond that?

Comment: @Krypton: Your code is UB. [basic.life]/1 (from N4606) says that an object with "non-vacuous initialization" (ie: one that doesn't have a trivial default constructor) will only have its lifetime begun by calling one of its constructors. `Test` has no default constructor (since you gave it a non-default constructor); it therefore has "non-vacuous initialization". You did not call a constructor to initialize it, and therefore the lifetime of the `Test` subobojects of the arrays has not begun. You access their value representation. And that's UB for an object who's lifetime has not started.

Comment: @Krypton: "*Although I'm far from an expert, I obviously know what I'm talking about.*" And yet you're wrong. Oh sure, your code will probably function as intended. But it is *undeniably* undefined behavior according to the C++ standard. And I just cited why.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for finding the standardies.  I summed it up as a comment on the OP's answer but it is nice to have the actual text.

Comment: @Krypton I know it because I recognize this. I have been that way before. Others here have probably been that way before. That is why they are able tell you it's bad practice. Because they have experienced it. We can understand your point of view, while you don't seem to be able to understand ours. Which indicates that those others here are more experienced.

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks for quoting the standard. While even the standard states that it could cause UB, it indeed is not when you run it.

Comment: I don't want to insult you with this or attack you. Everyone has been in this stage / will be. I just think it's helpfull to know that there are always people who know better and people should learn to recognize those.

Comment: @Krypton: "*While even the standard states that it could cause UB*" No, it says it *does* cause UB. That doesn't mean "does crash"; it means that the standard doesn't say what will happen. The implementation may very well do what you expect. But reliance on UB is not something you should do simply because you don't know it isn't UB.

Comment: @Hayt: I understand ur view. Just that probably we are differnt jobs. My job is more on researching the binary, and how it is parsed/run by the dynamic linker of the system. And yes from the developer point of view, you are not comfortable using something that you have never seen/done before.

Comment: @Krypton I have seen / done that before. But i know that some small changes to classes / alignment with packing etc. can change the whole memory layout and can cause quite hard to trace errors. Those practices are just hazardous and on larger projects / one with multiple people on it can cause hard to find/expensive errors in the long run.

Comment: @Hayt: if you have done that, why would you say the alignment can affect this? I did not set the attributes by using offset, didn't you see that? If you are not too sure about something, probably research about it first.

Comment: @Krypton yeah in your example it works because it's simple. The issue here is (and what everyone else has with this answer) in real life stuff is not that simple. classes are more complex etc. And there you can  create hard to trace side effects with this approach.

Comment: First I'm not saying it gonna work in a large system, but you cannot tell it won't either. Secondly this has absolutely nothing to do with error tracing (even with inheritance). You can access all the functions/attributes exactly the same way as they are with a normal C++ allocation/initialization.

Comment: The top voted answer is fine. You're just quibbling over the phrase "the only way," which is a technicality. That only makes the answer imperfect, it doesn't mean that other answers are better.

Comment: @Krypton no, you cannot access anything. Go browse CVE lists. You'll find vulnerabilities caused by this sort of wrong expectations. Then go get some basic C/C++ knowledge. You need to get a grasp of what undefined behavior means. It doesn't mean "it's defined to be whatever I want". It means it's not defined to be anything at all.

Comment: Example: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-8390

Comment: Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) it explains one reason you do not understand why your *expert* answer is not correct and getting down voted to oblivion.

Comment: I wasn’t able to judge the correctness of each answer, but I had an inkling that „correct“ and „incorrect“ weren’t as clear here as the OP made it look, and that the Galilei comparison was way off. Ah well.

Comment: there already are experts reviewing disputable answers, many have reviewed and weighed in on the answer you linked to. just because you do not agree with their judgement does not make them wrong, it [just means you do not understand their reasons.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)

Comment: When you're driving down the highway and everyone else is driving on the wrong side of the road and all the road signs are facing backwards, the simplest explanation is that everyone is driving wrong and that all the road workers put the signs wrong.

Comment: I don't suppose someone wants to create some doc examples of undefined behavior and how it differs from observed behavior of one compiler or environment?  I'm not being facetious when I say it's apparently an issue where some could use instruction, as seen here by references to the the false dichotomy of `cause UB (instead of compile)`.

Comment: @bitnine cve.mitre.org is ripe with examples. Maybe we should just link to the OpenSSL source :D

Comment: @Gimby Krypton's answer was plain wrong. It isn't a matter of style, it was just incorrect C++, and we wouldn't want newcomers to think otherwise. That is the reason I down-voted, but I can't speak for others. When I down-voted, it had +1 score, which means that it had already fooled someone.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Point taken.  Hm, since experience can be the best teacher, perhaps someone should make that format-hard-drive-on-UB compiler and give that a link?

Comment: After all this discussion, I'm just gonna drop two words here: Dunning-Kruger.

Comment: @Griwes that was more than 2 words ;)

Comment: @Hayt the part after the introduction of the comment was exactly two words. :P

Comment: Ah, and of course I've been late with that. *Sigh*.

Comment: @Griwes late? how? what?

Comment: @Hayt Jarrod Roberson's comment above.

Comment: @Griwes I see *sigh*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your suggestion has a key problem:

How would any "experts" we bring in via extraneous means (like a review queue for instance) differ from the people who normally come across questions/answers and vote on them? In fact, considering they'd be largely out of their area of expertise, these people would be *less* qualified to judge "disputable" content then the normal voter on these questions, which had to at least have enough interest to click them in the first place.

If by "experts" you mean moderators, that won't work, either. Our moderators (the elected ones) are explicitly not elected to judge *content and accuracy* of questions or answers. They're mainly there for resolving disputes and administrative issues.

In closing, I don't believe there's a better way to judge content worth then the one we have in place: Normal community voting.

Comment: Yeah u'r right. I guess we cannot do anything about it.

Answer (score 23):

@jaunchopanza's answer may be incorrect based on a technicality about English grammar--he uses the phrase "the only way", when there *may* be alternatives (but to be honest, I'm not at all sure there is any). Nonetheless, he outlines a technically correct method to do what the OP asked about. As such, while it might be open to a minor (bordering on trivial) improvement, I think it's quite a solid answer.

You answer is much more problematical. It uses `malloc` to allocate raw memory. You rarely want to allocate raw memory in C++, but if you really need to do so, you nearly always want to do that with `::operator new` rather than `malloc`.

It then attempts to assign the result from `malloc` to a pointer to a `Test`. This would work in C, but doesn't work (won't even compile) in C++. C allows an implicit conversion from `void *` to `T *` (for any arbitrary type `T`). C++ requires that such a conversion be done explicitly, such as by using a `static_cast` or C-style cast.

That is, this code:

```
// Bad code. If your C++ compiler accepts this, get a better compiler.
Test *t = malloc(10 * sizeof(Test));
```

...is what the standard calls "ill formed". The standard requires that a conforming implementation issue a "diagnostic" for this code. The usual implementation of that is that the compiler issues an error message, and your code won't compile. To make it compile, you need to add a cast:

```
// Bad code. Do not use
Test *t = (Test *)malloc(10 * sizeof(Test));
```

or:

```
// Still bad code. Don't use this either.
Test *t = static_cast<Test *>(malloc(10 * sizeof(Test));
```

or even:

```
// Minutely less bad code--but still don't use it.
Test *t = static_cast<Test *>(::operator new(10 * sizeof(Test)));
```

That allows the code to treat the block of raw memory as if it were objects of type `Abc`--but that doesn't change the fact that what it actually contains is really just raw, uninitialized memory, not objects at all. This is not what the question asked about though. It asked specifically about creating objects: "Can we create an array of objects of the class [...]". Even assuming we add the cast necessary to let your code compile, that's still not what it does--it doesn't create objects, it just allocates raw memory, the tells the compiler a lie to say that raw memory is objects.

Will Rogers (I think he was the one, anyway) once told a joke that started with asking the audience: "If you call a horse's tail a leg, how many legs does a horse have?"

The audience came back with the obvious answer: "five".

Will then pointed out: "No. It doesn't matter what you call its tail, a horse still only has four legs."

In this case, it doesn't matter what you call that raw memory, it's still just raw memory.

Trying to use that raw memory as if it were objects (without invoking ctors to make it into objects) gives undefined behavior. That's the C++ standard's code phrase for saying: "what you've done isn't really C++".

As given, your code won't even compile with any compiler of which I'm aware. With a cast added, it'll compile but still gives undefined behavior. It's bad code.

If SO were to form a group of experts in C++, I think I'd have about as much right as anybody to be part of that group. I've taken what action I can to give my opinion of this answer; in addition to pointing out its flaws here, I've also added my down-vote *and* voted to delete the answer.

Comment: You're a bully.

Comment: "*and voted to delete the answer*" While I agree with your conclusion obviously, I can't agree with the vote to delete. Why? Because having that answer there, with a highly negative score, tells people one thing: this is *wrong*. And given the number of C++ programmers who think that that kind of code is good code, that's a lesson people clearly still need. So while I certainly appreciate the sentiment, I think you're missing an opportunity for people to learn what *not to do*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: While I can certainly appreciate your idea, I'm still reminded of the old line that there's no such thing as negative publicity. I'm not sure even a massively negative score is enough to get people to reconsider writing code like this. If that's a point we want to make (and it might well be worth making) I think it should be in a question devoted specifically to why this should be avoided, so the answer contains a more directly statement about what's wrong with it.

Comment: I agreed this is such a bully... "Even assuming we add the cast necessary to let your code compile, that's still not what it does--it doesn't create objects, it just allocates raw memory, the tells the compiler a lie to say that raw memory is objects." You also realize this creates a raw memory and tells the compiler it is an object. And then you say no, no, no, this is bad, this is wrong and this causes UB. Then you quoted some standards and says it is not C++. You didn't even give an evidence how it is not working. In the end, it still works no matter how bad people think it is...

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes you mentioned the CVE that happened because of uninitialized memory read (or exactly memory set as OpenSSL is in C). Don't try to bully me with this. The piece of code that I pasted did not set the memory as the OP didn't want it. It could be added easily (see the snippet here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/893804819dbfb3be) and this topic has nothing to do with that CVE.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes if you want to give evidence, please find some CVE on "creating a raw memory and telling the compiler it is an object".

Comment: @JerryCoffin I forgot to talk about the casting. Casting is a just a means by the compiler for type checking. If you allocates the right memory size, you won't get any issue no matter what type casting you use. It's more of a coding pratice than correctness of the code.

Comment: What you're missing here is that real experts go by more than "works on my machine". You're wrong about what casting is (please cite evidence if you want to hold that claim). You need to learn more C++ before you can call yourself an expert.

Comment: I mentioned a CVE about uninitialized reads because the code in question did uninitialized reads (the first comment under it starts with "you have undefined behaviour because you're reading from uninitialized memory"). Real experts won't argue that if it works with some changes (which it doesn't, btw), it works without them, because that's a logical fallacy. Real experts use logic in their thought process and in their discourse.

Comment: @Krypton: What part of: "It won't even compile" did you miss? What basis can you give for claiming that it works when it won't even compile?

Comment: C'mon you claimed it won't even compile just because I forgot to cast when I published my answer. See the snippet I posted in coliru please. Tell me if you find a machine that this doesn't work and then we talk next.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I do use not use citation as a way to prove. In fact citation (if quoted from unrelated articles like your CVE) cannot prove anything, and sometimes can be more harm than good. The only way to prove is to see if it works. If you are able to use my code in a way that it is not working anymore, please go ahead and I will say sorry and admit it. If you don't find, please don't try to fool the people.

Comment: @Krypton "*The only way to prove is to see if it works*". Well, no it isn't. The language has a formal specification for a reason. But even if it were, you couldn't because you have *undefined behaviour*. Even the notion of "working" is out of the window here. Instead of arguing with people who know what they are talking about, your time would be better spent learning C++, understanding what undefined behaviour actually means, and, in general, learning to learn.

Comment: The same to you, you should have spent more time learning to accept the unconventional ways that you think wouldn't work.

Comment: Also, I don't need to run a code, but to find some citation and then I claim it won't work. Is this what you mean? Also run the code please, you will see the behavior is completely defined.

Comment: @Krypton You keep talking about "unconventional" like some kind of new-age healer. Your code is not unconventional. It is broken. Period. People who know enough C++ can see that. For whatever reason, you are refusing to learn from the opinion of a large number of people more qualified than yourself.

Comment: @Krypton For the nth time, read up on undefined behaviour and learn C++. There is no point discussing this any longer. Either you don't want to learn, or you know so little that you don't even understand what people have been telling you over and over again. Or both.

Comment: "Also, I don't need to run a code, but to find some citation and then I claim it won't work." No. You need to take a scientific approach to this. You cannot extrapolate from one observation without an explanation for the observation. Have you figured out an explanation for why the code works even though the language rules don't say so? (It's actually a simple explanation and doesn't contradict the language rules; it just implies extrapolation is not possible). People have given you solid explanations for why you cannot extrapolate (the language rules allow arbitrary unbounded behaviour).

Comment: At this point you can either claim that explanation is wrong by showing that the language rules are not those (should be easy to do so; the language rules are freely available online for perusal), or exhaustively run all possible programs using this feature and show they all work. Science!

Comment: Consider this thought experiment. I tell you that exact code crashed on my system. What do you surmise from that? Do you accuse me of lying? That would be disrespectful towards someone trying to help. Do you blame a compiler bug? You need to show how this behaviour differs from the specification, then. Do you accept my report and admit you're wrong?

Comment: I won't blame. Show me the code and the crash log please! If it really is, I would accept and say sorry. I'm not that immature not to accept the proofs.

Comment: Let's have another experiment thought. What if I am able to show a proof of a large scale production code running on thousands/million machines. Do you and the community say sorry and accept the whole community is wrong?

Comment: No. You still have no grounds for extrapolating to other programs. You need an explanation for why other programs also work. Science!

Comment: @Krypton Here's some output from that program on one system `%-+@+'!"(@)`. If you won't claim it's a compiler bug, and accept my honesty, then there's no other option than accepting you're wrong.

Comment: May I know the platform/compiler and the snippet u use please? If I'm able to reproduce I will accept.

Comment: The compiler is not freely available, sorry.

Comment: ^ alright then screenshot please?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/uH5SBR5.png

Comment: Code for that was copy&pasted from the answer.

Answer (score 23):

I'm gonna summarize this. There *are* experts who review disputable answers. They're the ones you're arguing against.

Comment: I can also summarise, while they can be the real experts, they cannot just simply accept something that is working but looks unconventional.

Comment: @Krypton Let's assume for a second that that particular specific piece of code does work. It doesn't matter. That specific piece of code is too small to do anything useful. I hope you read that in one second because I'm dropping the assumption now. You have been told countless times how and why this might break when you use the technique in slightly different code or different compilers or different compiler flags. The experts have accepted your evidence and explained why it's weak. The burden is on you to explain why the technique will always work despite the language rules saying otherwise.

Comment: What are those slightly different code or different compilers? Example please!

Comment: @Krypton sorry, you're the one claiming that showing it works is the only acceptable proof. This means that, by claiming this always works you burden yourself with having to write all possible programs using this and running them all. That's the only way to show they all work. Otherwise your answer is useless, because it only shows that some useless program works. I suggest you start writing them now, and wish you good luck.

Comment: @Krypton Your code doesn't work in the slightest. It might just happen to appear to work for you with a trivial sample program.

Comment: A simple example of how such things go awry is http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f1bdf9c53f0c5e1, which *should* segfault by your logic, but actually, doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

So after having a night to sleep over this: my 2 cents here.

There may be a usecase where the answer would be valid. And I mean a very small usecase. This would be in case of custom memory allocators (and even then you would call a constructor with `placement new`, so the answer would be at least "incomplete" then). Though just by the question and it's nature I doubt the OP is trying to implement those.

My **major** issue I have with the answer is that it **teaches bad practices**. While krypton even may know what happens there and all it's side effects, other people reading it or the OP of the question probably do not know about these.

Stackoverflow is not about showing off what "hacks" you can do, its about providing quality answers to valuable questions.

If people post such answers (which is valid in my point of view because they can have their uses) they also should **explain** in detail what it does and make readers aware of any negative side effects and what they are doing. This answer though only shows an "abuse" of the c++ language without explaining why it works and that it can go bad the moment a constructor does some custom things (because the constructor will never be called) etc.

In general if you post some "advanced" things in your answer you should explain them if there is no obvious documentation about the feature available (and even then). Most people who come to Stack Overflow for answers are not experts and handing out dangerous code to people who are just learning is like giving a gun to a child.

Comment: SO is not so much about teaching, it is more about writing the course material. People who try to teach on SO are the ones that write all the angry meta rants :)

Comment: OK teaching may have been a bad wording. But we strife to make the programming world a better place ;) ( I hope )

Comment: Can't argue with that :) -> "Stackoverflow is not about showing off what "hacks" you can do, its about providing quality answers to valuable questions"

Comment: Well I'm sorry for having better explanation, it was a tired working day back then, a bit procrastinated to give explanation, draw diagrams and stuffs to illustrate how could that work. As for warming, I did put one at the end of the post, but I guess no one here saw that and completely denied my way. The over-reaction of the community is just another proof, the community is not always right...

Comment: @Gimby changed ;)

Comment: @Krypton thats what happens when you raise awareness on those thing on meta. You get a pretty "amplified" reaction. I usually also put warnings or similar in **bold** with the word **warning** before it or so to make sure people don't overlook it easily.

Comment: There's more steps needed in custom allocators, like... actually constructing an object. You can't call raw memory containing no objects an object (well... you can if you are in pre-C++17 world where you can construct POD types without calling their constructors, but since that's changing soon - and actually fixes a bug - is not very future-proof). The code is not valid C++ code, and the only way to prove otherwise is find wording that says it's correct (tip: there's no such wording, and even less in the current C++17 draft).

Comment: @Griwes Yeah thats why I mentioned you need to call the constructor with `placement new` after you allocated the memory.

Comment: Gee, it feels good just to collaborate, discuss pros and cons and just all around have an open mind about things, right? Stack Overflow is such a great place if you don't isolate yourself.

Comment: @Gimby not sure if sarcastic.... but yes it feels good though not everyone is that way. And the "loudest" here or the one you remember the most are those which are not sadly.

Comment: @Hyat Ah, sorry, somehow I missed that part. Not awake enough yet, it seems. :D

Comment: @Griwes I can see how people can overlook this. that's why I edited it to highlight that part. Thx for the "tip" ;)

Comment: I'd actually disagree that it's a C++ answer at all: A language is by nature abstracted.  Undefined behavior is where the language ends, leaving only compiler-specific behavior.  Any answer that ventures into undefined behavior is no longer an answer on how to solve a problem within that language, but instead one on how to produce a certain behavior in a limited set of environments (regardless of how large or small that set at a point in time).  It's possible an UB answer could be an answer to some "how do I" questions, but never an answer on how to perform a task **within a language**.

Comment: @bitnine you are right there. the undefined behavor is caused because no constructor is caused on the objects. Thats why I mentioned that still a constructor should be called with `placement new`